# Nginx Proxy Pass dont acceppts user & password

Tags: nginx

i need to proxy pass one URL from my internal network, that looks like this here:

```
http://<user><passwd><ipaddress>:<port>/cgi-bin/mjpg/video.cgi?channel=1&subtype=1
```

But this configuration always ends up in an error:

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid port in upstream "user:passwd@192.168.133.122:8080/cgi-bin/mjpg/video.cgi?channel=1&subtype=1" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:15
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

The only working way i get nginx to work is this one:

```
server {

listen 80;
root /var/www/html;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
                
location /video.cgi {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.133.122:8080/cgi-bin/mjpg/video.cgi?channel=1&subtype=1;
    }
}
```

But in this configuration the User and the Password are not included. Is there a way to get user&password also in the proxy_pass?

thanks
Franz